# Authentication between Laravel5.5 api and angular2 using passport, oauth2

Tags: angular, laravel-5.3

I'v built an API in Laravel 5.5 and a client in angular 4, for user authentication I use passport with Oauth2, when I register the client to my server I got Client_id and Client_secret. but my question is: I don't want to send client_id and client_secret along username and password in every login, I want to send only username and password from client to api.